# JavaScript window.location.href base64 encode

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script>
         window.location.href = 'data:text/html;base64,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';
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

What is the reason why this code didn't work for me?

Comment: __Observation__: in svg you can use the [<image>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) tag. No need of a foreign object for this. However you may have another reason to use the foreign object.

Comment: you are applying the XHTML namespace, so it would make sense that `<img>` doesn't work and needs to be closed `<img/>` right? If you want to use an `img` that isn't self-closing, then don't declare the `html` as XHTML

Comment: SVG is XML and contain URL link to images.  You image in a png and doesn't need to be in a HTML tag.

Comment: In case you're still interested in an answer after all this time ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs#common_problems: _"Security issues: A number of security issues (for example, phishing) have been associated with data URLs, and navigating to them in the browser's top level. To mitigate such issues, **top-level navigation to data: URLs is blocked in all modern browsers**."_